# Teraterm not connecting to Linux system from a new Laptop

Tags: teraterm

I am in the progress of migrating from a desktop to laptop and have gotten stumped. On the PC, I am able to connect to a Linux system without issue. When I attempt to connect to the same system, it fails. Interactive login just repeatedly asks for my password. I am able to login to other Linux systems without issue from the laptop. I have upgraded the teraterm version to portable instance of 5.0 from 4.106 with no change in how it works.

Here is the SSH dump I see when attempting to connect.

```
2023-10-25 18:39:34.785Z [23012] SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE was received.
2023-10-25 18:39:34.785Z [23012] Server reports supported authentication method mask = 65580
2023-10-25 18:39:34.785Z [23012] method list from server: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
2023-10-25 18:39:34.800Z [23012] CRYPT_set_random_data: RAND_bytes call
2023-10-25 18:39:34.800Z [23012] finish_send_packet_special: built packet info: aadlen:4, enclen:80, padlen:13, datalen:100, maclen:16, Encrypt Mode:AEAD, MAC mode:EtM
2023-10-25 18:39:34.800Z [23012] SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST was sent do_SSH2_authrequest(). (method 3)
2023-10-25 18:39:34.847Z [23012] SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE was received.
2023-10-25 18:39:34.848Z [23012] User authentication will be shown by 3 method.
2023-10-25 18:39:37.631Z [23012] CRYPT_set_random_data: RAND_bytes call
2023-10-25 18:39:37.633Z [23012] finish_send_packet_special: built packet info: aadlen:4, enclen:48, padlen:10, datalen:68, maclen:16, Encrypt Mode:AEAD, MAC mode:EtM
```

For obvious reasons, I cannot post the whole log. I DO receive the authentication banner. This is failing at password entry. Again, this works fine on my old desktop PC.